# Cortana voice command do not start app properly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, cortana

I tried Cortana voice command to start my app,

but it works only when app is suspended. When app is closed, it shows Splashscreen and then app fails. I'm not able to to catch any exception.

A have exactly the same code as in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn630430.aspx and Microphone Capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a Voice Command activates the app, this method is going to be called and OnLaunched is not. Because of that we need similar code to the code we have in OnLaunched

```
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

if (rootFrame == null)
{
     rootFrame = new Frame();
     rootFrame.CacheSize = 1;
     Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
     rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When an app is opened using Voice Commands, you need to handle it on *app.OnActivated* method:

```
    protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle when app is launched by Cortana
        if (e.Kind == ActivationKind.VoiceCommand)
        {
            VoiceCommandActivatedEventArgs commandArgs = e as VoiceCommandActivatedEventArgs;
            SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult = commandArgs.Result;

            string voiceCommandName = speechRecognitionResult.RulePath[0];
            string textSpoken = speechRecognitionResult.Text;
            IReadOnlyList<string> recognizedVoiceCommandPhrases;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("voiceCommandName: " + voiceCommandName);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("textSpoken: " + textSpoken);

            switch (voiceCommandName)
            ...
```

If you need more information how to integrate it, please see this [link](http://talkitbr.com/2015/07/13/integrando-a-cortana-em-seu-aplicativo-windows-10/)